# SQL If statement and merging 2 queries

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query that would look at a date column in a database and add 14 days, my problem is that the query needs to look at a document state column, look for `Unprocessed` and partially processed and add 14 or 7 days respectfully.

Eg, if an order came today it will be unprocessed and the date must add 14 days before it gets cleared from the system, if a document is partially processed the date must add 7 days before getting cleared from the system.

Also the 2 queries need to be merged into one, can anyone please help?

```
SELECT * 
FROM ZS_vwSOA_PendingApproval 
WHERE [Document State] IN ('Unprocessed', 'Partially Processed') 

SELECT Date, DATEADD(day, 14, Date) AS [Expiration Date] 
FROM ZS_vwSOA_PendingApproval
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    CASE [Document State]
        WHEN 'Unprocessed' THEN DATEADD(day, 14, Date)
        WHEN 'Partially Processed' THEN DATEADD(day, 7, Date)
    END AS [Expiration Date]
FROM ZS_vwSOA_PendingApproval
WHERE [Document State] IN ('Unprocessed', 'Partially Processed')
```